# Discord Bot's "KICK" command is not working JDA

Tags: java, discord-jda

just got started in JDA v4.1.1_137 today. I've had trouble making a kick command while other YouTubers have gained success while using it. I don't know why it only happens to me.

I use `event.getGuild().kick()` with `net.dv8tion.jda.api`.

Here are the variables:

```java
        String authorID = event.getAuthor().getId();
        String messageID = event.getMessageId();
        String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();
        Member member = event.getMember();
        Message msg = event.getMessage();

        Member author = event.getMessage().getMember();
        String channelID = event.getChannel().getId();
        String authorFull = event.getAuthor().getAsTag();
        String Channel = event.getChannel().getName();
```

Here is the code with the kicking section:

```java
if (message.toLowerCase().equals("m!kick")) {
            if (event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers().isEmpty()){
                return;
            }
            Member target = msg.getMentionedMembers().get(0);
            if (!member.canInteract(target) || !member.hasPermission(Permission.KICK_MEMBERS)) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("You are missing permission to kick this member").queue();
                return;
            }

            final Member selfMember = event.getGuild().getSelfMember();

            if (!selfMember.canInteract(target) || !selfMember.hasPermission(Permission.KICK_MEMBERS)) {
                event.getChannel().sendMessage("I am missing permissions to kick that member").queue();
                return;
            }



            event.getGuild()
                    .kick(target, "hi")
                    .reason("hi")
                    .queue(
                            (__) -> event.getChannel().sendMessage("Kick was successful").queue(),
                            (error) -> event.getChannel().sendMessageFormat("Could not kick %s", error.getMessage()).queue()
                    );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your command syntax is something along the lines of `!kick @member`.

So you'll probably want to check if the message *starts with* `!kick`, instead of checking for equality. Or preferrably, check if the substring before the first blank space equals `!kick`.

Right now, if you were to execute the command with the correct syntax, you wouldn't make it past the first condition because the string will be something like `!kick @member`. Conversely, if the first condition in your snippet is true, `event.getMessage().getMentionedMembers()` is empty and your method returns.

Comment: It took me SO long to think about that, now that I think about it, I am like: wait if I do "m!kick ..." doesn't even work because it won't trigger.